# Django 1.8 Cannot load the css template

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-1.8

I have CSS file at `/ecomstore/static/css.css`

I have already linked the css to the base.html within head tags by

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css.css" />
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from ecomstore import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^catalog/','preview.views.home'),
    # url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
# { 'document_root' : '/home/yogesh/ecomstore/static' })
]

urlpatterns = [
# other commented code here
    url(r'^catalog/?','preview.views.home'),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{ 'document_root' : '/home/yogesh/ecomstore/static/' }),
]
```

Settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'templates')],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/yogesh/ecomstore/static/"
```

Despite all this stuff i dont know why my css template is not loading. Also in the terminal i am getting the following indicating some sort of error.

[24/Nov/2015 11:11:36] "GET /static/css.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1735

Comment: Show us you `STATIC` settings, not `TEMPLATES`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `{% static %}` template tag:

   ```
   {% load staticfiles %}
   ```
2. Configure static files dir in your settings and do not hardcode the path in your urlconf:

   ```
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
       '/var/www/static/',
   )
   ```
3. Make sure you're serving static files during development:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
        # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```
4. Check that static file dir `/home/yogesh/ecomstore/static/` is readable by your django process.

Answer (score 0):

## Static files

Store your files in `/ecomstore/static/ecomstore/css.css` instead of `/ecomstore/static/css.css` because Django look by default in all folders  `<app_name/static/<app_name>`, then you don't have to had these folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable.

**Django documentation** :

> Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For
>   example my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg.

Read this for more
information and configure your project : [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

## Templates

You did also a mistake in the configuration of your template. When you use `os.path.json` function, you don't have to have a `/` at the last folder. Just use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`

## Serving static file during development

Concerning serving static files, if you use the django built-in server, you don't have to configure anything, Django serve them by default. However, if you use gunicorn or uWSGI, yes you have to configure your project to serve static files.

You have to add this in your main `<project_name>/<project_name>/urls.py` file:

```python
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Now, your server will server static file based on `STATIC_URL` that you configured in your `<project_name>/<project_name>/settings.py` file.

Read this for more information : [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)